# Como puedo agregar desde c# controles asp Literal para n graficas Highchart

Tags: c#, asp, highcharts

Necesito crear n controles Literal desde programacion Asp C#, para crear varias graficas highchart pero no he tenido exito

```
  <% = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(contenido_html) %>
```

desde c#

```
html+="<asp:Literal ID="_nombre_iteracion" runat="server"></asp:Literal>"
```

Comment: porque quieres hacer esto desde codigo c#? no seria mejor exponer algun webmethod que envie los datos por json, entonces creas html usando jquery o javascript. Si puedes evita crear html dinamico desde codigo sevidor

Comment: Pero como?, algun ejemplo refrencia, jejeje, es que necesito enmtregar mis graficas para mañana

Comment: lo edite manualemnte para que el mismo highchart apunte apara dos literales ya creadas manualmente pero en una sola me salen los dos graficas

Comment: ehh bueno con el tema del lapso de tiempo para la entrega no puedo hacer nada, pero si aconsejo que el html lo generes del lado cliente en base a los datos que obtienes desde el servidor por medio de una llamada ajax, la cual devolvera json

Comment: Algun ejemplito que hayas visto por ahi entre tus conocimientos por favor

Answer (score 0):

Aconsejo que el `html` lo generes del lado cliente en base a los datos que obtienes desde el servidor por medio de una llamada `ajax`, la cual devolvera `json`.

Algo como lo planteado aqui

[Highcharts Asp.net: Create Pie chart with jQuery ajax in C# (MS SQL database)](https://codepedia.info/highcharts-asp-net-create-pie-chart-with-jquery-ajax-in-c-sharp-ms-sql-database/)

Veras que rea un grafico pero los datos los obtiene usando

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService.asmx/getCityPopulation",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess_,
    error: OnErrorCall_
});
```

esa es la llamada ajax al servidor, el cual invoca

```
[WebMethod]
public List<cityPopulation> getCityPopulation(List<string> pData)
{
   //codigo
}
```

ese `WebMethod` en el sevidor enviara un json al cliente y lo usaras de origen de datos para el reporte o tambien aplica para generar html dinamicamente

[Bind Drilldown Highchart in ASP.NET Using jQuery and Ajax](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c3a146/bind-drilldown-highchart-in-Asp-Net-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: Ok, lo revisare en estos momentos, toda la tarde y noche del dia de hoy, a ver si mas tarde encuentro algo de apoyo, gracias nuevamente por tu tiempo  Alejandro

Comment: No se si es válido dar seguimiento al tema de este modo pero en relacion a lo anterior, necetio obtener el arreglo de datos de una List<Series> Lista_de_Series = new List<Series>(); esta lista contiene n arreglos de datos,  foreach (Series var_serie in lista_de_series)
        {
            if (var_serie .Name.Equals("PRODUCCION MANUAL"))
            {
                  pero no puedo acceder a la coleccion de datos de este arreglo, var_serie.Data

Comment: la verdad ni idea a que var_serie.Data haces referencia, pero el codigo cliente esta separado del codigo servidor, y la forma correcta de comunicalros e spor medio de una llamada ajax

Comment: Es una propiedad de Series, pero ya quedo resuelto, solo que aun tengo pendiente lo de generarlo desde maquina cliente, con la ayuda que me pasaste

Comment: la idea de obtener un json desde el webmethod es que en el cliente puedas usar una libreria de template como ser https://github.com/mach3/js-jquery-render para generar el html dinamicamente, pero del lado cliente, no generar html desde el servidor, esa es una pesima idea

Comment: No habra un ejemplito descargable?, ya en intentado hacer un ejemplo pero no he levantado